# How to return struct or ptr to struct from ActiveX C++ class method

Tags: c++, com, struct, activex, marshalling

I have an un-managed C++ DLL originally written in MSVC++ 6.0.  It has a couple classes and a few standalone C functions which I need to call from C# .NET 4.0.  I have had several false starts on this.  I know there are several ways to do this (Convert to COM, MC++ wrapper, PInvoke) but it hasn't been entirely clear which is the most straightforward.  My current approach is to convert the C++ DLL to ActiveX control.  The issue I've run into is that when trying to recreate the methods in a VS 2010 C++ ActiveX project the Class Wizard does not allow any return types except fundamental types, CString or pointer to CWnd.  How do I return either a copy of a structure or a pointer to a structure?  It doesn't seem possible to return as a parameter either since the types for the method parameters have the same type limitations as the return type.

[image: Allowed ActiveX Return Types]

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to return unmanaged data to managed code (or to any code). If your ActiveX class is allocating this memory, then your ActiveX class is responsible for its de-allocation.

A common approach for solving this problem is to have a method that returns an HRESULT and that receives raw data with data size, or if you want something more managed-like it can receive a safe-array of bytes (this can be mapped to byte[] in managed code).

In your method implementation you can overwrite the array with your structure's data.

Back in managed code, you will need to marshal the structure as a byte-array in order to pass it to your new method. The method [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx#Y0) may help for this task.

In order to add a method to your class that receives a pointer as parameter, you can use the "add method" context menu option of the default interface of your activex control. See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.  However, looking up [HRESULT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HRESULT) in Wikipedia it appears to be simply a 32 bit error/status code return.  How do I use that to return a set of raw bytes and size?

Comment: The thing is, you will not *return* the raw data, you will create the data in managed code and pass it to your unmanaged code as a normal parameter so that you can write your resulting data on it. You can see the raw data as a blank piece of paper, you will pass the paper to your GetCurrentLookupItem method and you will fill out the paper inside this method. I will try to include some code tomorrow if I have time.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense but I'm still wondering how I create a method in the ActiveX control that can receive an empty raw data buffer to be filled by the ActiveX method, if the only allowed parameter types in Class Wizard are fundamental scalar types (BYTE, FLOAT, INT, UINT, HRESULT, etc).  Do I use an HRESULT parameter and cast it to pointer to struct or something similar?

Comment: You should see a few more options for parameter types, you should also have LPBYTE, PBYTE, SAFEARRAY, VARIANT etc. You should also have IDispatch*, IUNKNOWN* and you should be able to specify each parameter as [out] or [in].

Comment: Those other types are not appearing in the Class Wizard dialog either for return type or parameter type.  The only types allowed are those shown in screen capture posted with the original question, namely:
bool, char double, float HRESULT int, long long double, short, unsigned char, unsigned int, unsigned long, void DWORD, WORD, BYTE, FLOAT, INT, UINT, LRESULT CString, CString^, CWnd *

I am running Visual Studio 2010 Professional Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1 Rel and the project type is a C++ Active X Control

Comment: Ok using **Add: Add Method...** context menu from the `DTest` item in `TestLib` folder does allow the the full list of types you listed.  What I'm now understanding is that using the context menu **Add: Add Function...** on the `CTestCtrl` class directly only adds an internal method without exposing it to the COM interface. Right?

Comment: It also appears that using the **Class Wizard...** context menu only adds an internal method.  Curious that the **Class Wizard...** and the **Add Function...** operations give different lists of allowable types although they seem to both be adding internal methods to the selected class.  For example **Class Wizard...** allows CString, CString& and CWnd* and **Add Function...** doesn't.  Any idea why that is?  Thanks @yms for the education.

Comment: @JonN I could write a book with all the issues and weirdnesses I have found with this user interface, but it would end up being a bad comedy...

Comment: The difference with Add Method makes sense though, since ActiveX objects are supposed to be used through pointers to the interfaces they implement rather than a pointer to the class. In some programming languages you may end up ruining your memory managment if you do not do it this way (Delphi for example)